# Are measures for Isolation and Frustration of Need for Relatedness interchangeable?

Tags: social-psychology

I am looking to measure satisfaction/frustration of the psychological need for relatedness (self-determination theory) at work. Have seen the scales by Van den Broeck et al. (2010), Longo et al (2016), and Chen et al. (2015) in this regard.

But, scales measuring isolation, e.g., Orhan et al. (2016), seem a better fit for the situation.

Can I use the presence/absence of isolation as a stand-in for frustration/satisfaction of need for relatedness? Are they interchangeable?

Please advise.

---

References:

Chen, B., Vansteenkiste, M., Beyers, W., Boone, L., Deci, E. L., Van der Kaap-Deeder, J., ... & Ryan, R. M. (2015). Basic psychological need satisfaction, need frustration, and need strength across four cultures. Motivation and emotion, 39(2), 216-236.

Longo, Y., Gunz, A., Curtis, G. J., & Farsides, T. (2016). Measuring need satisfaction and frustration in educational and work contexts: The Need Satisfaction and Frustration Scale (NSFS). Journal of Happiness Studies, 17(1), 295-317.

Orhan, M. A., Rijsman, J. B., & Van Dijk, G. M. (2016). Invisible, therefore isolated: Comparative effects of team virtuality with task virtuality on workplace isolation and work outcomes. Revista de Psicología del Trabajo y de las Organizaciones, 32(2), 109-122.

Van den Broeck, A., Vansteenkiste, M., De Witte, H., Soenens, B., & Lens, W. (2010). Capturing autonomy, competence, and relatedness at work: Construction and initial validation of the Work‐related Basic Need Satisfaction scale. Journal of occupational and organizational psychology, 83(4), 981-1002.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Can you please [edit] your question to provide details in a references section on what Van den Broeck et al. (2010), Longo et al (2016), Orhan et al. (2016) and Chen et al. (2015) refer to?  That way others who may not be familiar can review them

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thanks! Made the changes